# type name not allowed, accessing constant variable from main()

Tags: c++

constants.h

```
 #include <string>
class constants
{
    static std::string FILE_PATH;
};
```

constants.cpp

```
#include "constants.h"

class constants{
public:
    std::string constants::FILE_PATH = "G:\\TextFile.txt";
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "txtFileGenerator.h"
#include "constants.h"
int main(){
    txtFileGenerator(constants.FILE_PATH);
}
```

Hello, given the above three files, why cant i access the public static string variable using constants.FILE_PATH? i get a "type name not allowed" error.

Solution:

main.cpp

```
#include "txtFileGenerator.h"
#include "constants.h"

std::string constants::FILE_PATH = "G:\\TextFile.txt";

int main(){
    txtFileGenerator(constants::FILE_PATH);

}
```

constants.h

```
#include <string>
class constants
{
public:
     static std::string FILE_PATH;
};
```

Comment: Do you really have two classes with the same name?

Comment: one is called constants.h while the other is constants.cpp

Comment: Try `constants::FILE_PATH` instead?

Comment: @sutoL Those are file names. You still have defined two different classes called `constants`. Time to go back to basics.

Comment: "constants::FILE_PATH" cannot be defined in the current scope i get this error instead.

Comment: **std::string constants::FILE_PATH = "G:\\TextFile.txt";** constants should already be assigned?

Comment: constants are usually implemented within a namespace, not a class.  You  then mark your variables as extern rather than static.

Answer (score 3):

The implementation in the `.cpp` file should just be:

```
std::string constants::FILE_PATH = "G:\\TextFile.txt";
```

And not be within another class declaration with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

This first problem is here:

```
class constants{
public:
    std::string constants::FILE_PATH = "G:\\TextFile.txt";
};
```

This redefines the class, which is not valid. To define the static variable it should be just:

```
    std::string constants::FILE_PATH = "G:\\TextFile.txt";
```

(i.e. without the enclosing class)

You probably also need a `public:` in `constants.h`

This is also wrong:

```
txtFileGenerator(constants.FILE_PATH);
```

To access a static variable of a type `T` you use `T::x` not `T.x` so it should be `constants::FILE_PATH`

(You use `t.x` to access a *non-static* member of an object `t`)

Comment: constants::FILE_PATH" cannot be defined in the current scope, this new error occurs in main()

Comment: @sutoL: Which is a correct error. Jonathan's answer already shows you the scope in which it _should_ be defined.

Comment: so i don't need to implement a constant.cpp declaration of the header file?

Comment: You need to define the static member. You can do that in constants.cpp if you want (or do it in any other .cpp file), but you need to fix the syntax, as shown in my answer.

Comment: Yes i redefined in constants.cpp but it shows "
 
constants::FILE_PATH" cannot be defined in the current scope" unless i defined it in main().

Comment: Impossible. It sounds like you are still putting it inside `class constants { ... };`, so stop doing that! You seem to be trying to write Java in C++. You do not need a file for every class, and you do not need to re-open the `class constants {` scope in constants.cpp to define the members declared in constants.h